# how can i make div or id visible only to logged in wordpress author

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, backend, navbar, wp-nav-menu-item

The menu item contains data that should only be visible to the wordpress author of the data.

```html
<a id="listing_tab_documents_toggle" data-section-id="documents" class="listing-tab-toggle toggle-tab-type-custom" data-options="{}">
```

Is there any way to display this id only for the wp author?

Comment: It looks as though this is something that should be generated by the backend when it creates the menu using the is_user_logged_in() and similar Wordpress functions in PHP. You cannot safely leave it up to the frontend to decide what to show as the user can change the code in the browser dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate menu for logged user and add this link into that menu only and call menu with condition of `is_user_logged_in()` and another options you can hide with CSS as well as like default this: `a#listing_tab_documents_toggle{display:none;} body.logged-in a#listing_tab_documents_toggle{display:block;}`

Comment: thanks. but that only partially solves the problem. there are several users on the site. each user can create posts. but only the user who is the author should see the id="listing_tab_documents_toggle". other users are not allowed to see this. if it is possible.